# SyntaxError with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mongoose

I want to create an application with a Mongo database on Heroku. Local on my PC the application works as expected. But when I use node --harmony to run the application and I push it to Heroku, I get following error message:

```
/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:208 
return conn.openUri(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2]).then(() => this)
                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

This looks for me as would the lambda expression causes the error. And because it is in the mongoose library code I can not change it.
Do I have to use a certain version or set a specific parameter that it works?

Before, I tried it without the --harmony flag. Then I got following error:

```
/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:7
const Schema = require('./schema');
^^^^^

SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
```

Is there a possibility to fix these problems with the mongoose library (I have similar problems also with the dotenv library)?

Kind regards,
Wolfgang

Comment: Which versions of NodeJS do you use on local PC and on Herocu?

Answer (score 0):

This must be because of your node version on heroku, it is not supporting the es6.
either update your version on heroku or replace your const with var and your arrow functions with traditional style functions.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.
Using node 8.9.4 instead of ~0.10.13 in my package.json fixed this problem :)